# typescript static type checking ES module exports

Tags: typescript

Is a way to static type checking es module export? as the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDMEsBsFMDoAuBnAsAKFgDwA4HsAnRUAYzwDtlitQBeUAFg23yNIqtAE87QByAO4ALAIaJYAN1gE+zXIWJlKxcHjy8AFAEo6APlAAmDBhChEQ2KEjlxBcCJKWAJrGQkCkAEauzF0MLFfSwBbPCcAVzhQFgU0dGtbe0dQAFkwyMsAbwxQXNAsAC5GHLyuIqoPcgBzEtzVPCLtPVBycODvAgwAXwwgA) describe below

```
// file.ts
export const x = 4
export const y = 'whatever'
export const foo = () => 2

// the interface describes the what the module exports
interface Module {
    x: 4
    y: string
    foo: () => number
}
```

I want the exports in file.ts satisfy the interface Module. Can typescript handle this? Or any issues related to this problem, I can't find in the github repo

Comment: I mean, [this works](https://tsplay.dev/w8AG4N)... does that meet your needs? If not, could you demonstrate with a [mre] via a properly configured web IDE project (like maybe StackBlitz or something that supports multiple files)?

Comment: @jcalz Thx your comment first. What you show is a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) aka `internal modules` in typescript. But what I want is type checking for ES module. I add a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-re9hsg?file=index.ts), when I try to import  x from file.ts.  you will find out that ts complains that file.ts is not a (ES) module cause it‘s a namespace. Besides,  I found that issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38511 is related to this question

Comment: I think there's been a miscommunication. Let's start over.  [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sndmct?file=index.ts) is a stackblitz demo showing a possible solution in a multi-file environment.  If `file.ts`'s exports fail to match `Module` there will be an error in `fileTsConstraint.ts`.  Does this meet your needs?

Comment: @jcalz  This not what I want, it does not meet my needs. I want a constraint to ensure a file export member correctly. See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2qv625?file=file.ts), I have similar file called file.ts, file2.ts, file3.ts, and I want their exports have the same shape, which means they all satisfy the Module interface

Comment: For that example I would do [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bmmjvx?file=moduleConstraints.ts), which will produce a compiler warning if and only if one of your files is not exporting a valid `Module`.  There is no direct annotation of imports, as in ms/TS#38511, but there are definitely ways to have the compiler type check your modules for you, albeit more indirectly.  If the way I've presented doesn't meet your needs, can you explain, in detail, how and why?

Comment: @jcalz I like your dynamic imports way to type check the modules, and gonna use it in my testing. It do meet my needs now, But I still want direct annotation of imports. Here is the situation in my team: we have some plugins written in ES modules, and we rely on the named exports. Besides, the plugin system is cross team, so having a constraint to describes the module is better, if so, when someone is writing plugin, he would know what should he export. Thx for your patient about the question

Comment: Okay I've written up an answer capturing what we've discussed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, there is currently no way to *annotate* that a module's exports conform to a particular type, nor is there a way to annotate the `import` statement on the consuming side.  Issues [microsoft/TypeScript#420](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420) and [microsoft/TypeScript#38511](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38511) are open feature requests for such functionality, but I wouldn't be optimistic about seeing any changes there in the near future.  Still, you might go to those issues and give them your .

The compiler certainly *knows* the type of the module, though, and so as a workaround you could make an assignment somewhere which will work if and only if the module conforms to your type.

For your example, that could be test code somewhere in your project like:

```
async function checks() {
  let check: Module = await import('./file');
}
```

If that succeeds, great.  If not, it will tell you what exported member(s) of file.ts fail to conform to `Module`.

Obviously this is a workaround since the type check is in a separate location from the exporting module.  But it's better than having no type check at all.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bmmjvx?file=moduleConstraints.ts)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38511

this issue is related to the question, was opened on 13 May 2020, and still opened form now