# How to ensure that a file exports conform to a certain shape?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if it's possible to enforce the shape of an ESM file's exports without turning it into a class export, e.g. I'd want `square.ts`, `triagle.ts`, `circle.ts`, etc to all have the same export shapes:

```
{
  numSides: () => number,
  to3D: () => 3DShape,
}
```

`square.ts`:

```
export function numSides() {
  return 4;
}

export function to3D() {
  return new Cube();
}
```

With Common JS I could do something like:

```
module.exports = { numSides, to3D } as shape
```

Trying the same thing in ESM throws an error on `as shape`

Comment: Probably only as a separate script using compiler api

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297129/typescript-static-type-checking-es-module-exports .  There's currently no way to do this directly, unfortunately.